# Conversion to ‘int’ from ‘float’ may alter its value

Tags: c, floating-point, int, rounding, c99

My code:

```
#inlcude <math.h>
#include "draw.h"  /*int draw(int x, int y)*/

draw(rintf(10 * x), rintf(8 * y));
```

I get this warning:  Conversion to ‘int’ from ‘float’ may alter its value.

I can't change `draw` to float, since I need it to draw points. So rounding is inevitable. Any ideas?

Comment: Explicitly casting to `int` may help you. Or changing `rintf` may be an (not so good) alternative.

Comment: take int draw(float x, float y)

Comment: What is the type of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Why do you use `rintf()` instead of `nearbyintf()`?

Comment: @FUZxxl From `man nearbyintf`: "`rint()` is typically much more performant than `nearbyint()` if the application does not depend on flags being preserved". This application does not depend on flags being preserved.

Comment: I fixed it. First as ch3rub7 suggested (though at first I didn't want to) changed int draw(float x, float y). Then in my grid array `char grid [x][y]` explicitly casted to int. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user4325010 If `draw` works on integer coordinates, does not seem like a particularly good fix to have it take `float` arguments.

Comment: @Arkku That's because `rintf()` raises an exception when the argument isn't already an integer and has a fast-path for these cases.

Comment: @user4325010 Overall, I'd say your approach of enabling strict warnings and then working to suppress them through code changes while keeping the same behaviour is wrong. For instance, if `draw` actually works on integers, you've made the code worse by having it take `float` arguments because the caller now needs to be aware that it doesn't actually support fractional coordinates despite the (now misleading) argument type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `rintf` is `float` which produces the warning. You can either explicitly cast to `int` to suppress the warning (i.e., `(int) rintf(10 * x)`, or you could use another way of rounding (e.g., if the values are known to be non-negative, `(int) (10.0f * x + 0.5f)`) or `lrint` (preferably from `tgmath.h`), although it returns a `long` which may cause another warning depending on your compiler and settings.

Comment: `(int) rintf (10 * x)` gives "warning: cast from function call of type ‘float’ to non-matching type ‘int’". Some values are negative. I assume to get another since my compiler setting are very strict. (`-std=c99 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wbad-function-cast  -Wconversion -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes`)

Comment: @user4325010 If you enable warnings beyond `-Wall`, you should be prepared to get some warnings which can be safely ignored. In this case it is unlikely that you can use any of the functions returning a floating point value to suppress the `bad-function-cast` warning (or if you can suppress it with some trickery, you've probably made the code worse)…

Comment: @user4325010 But, yeah, even with `-Weverything` I can get `clang` to accept `(int) lrint(10 * x)`.